# Is this a UML Diagram? (As used in Design Patterns)

Tags: c#, uml

I want to learn about Design Patterns and everywhere I see diagrams like this:

[image]

Is it UML or something else? I just need a quick reference to learn what do each of different lines mean? which one is inheritance, etc..

Comment: yep that is good enough for me. Thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: Its quite a big subject for one answer. The diagram above is a class diagram in UML which shows the entities, behaviour and relationships of a program. You will find a lot out by researching Gang of Four and their 23 patterns http://geekswithblogs.net/subodhnpushpak/archive/2009/09/18/the-23-gang-of-four-design-patterns-.-revisited.aspx

Regarding the diagram you posted you could research Class and Interface Representation and theyre members in UML and Inheritance and Compostion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1** Yes it is UML. You can read more (with examples) about class diagrams and other UML diagrams e.g. at http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html

[image]

**2** Although it is possible to Google out and print and pin up on your notice board some "`UML cheat sheet`" or "`UML quick reference card`" (e.g. http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml).

**3** it is much better to first read a good book so that you know what is/is_not possible what is the structural/behavioral modeling etc. Explaining UML is not a thing that can be done on 1 single sheet of paper or in one single Stack Overflow answer

Answer (score 9):

Here is a key that I found [here](http://cs.sjsu.edu/~drobot/cs146/UMLDiagrams.htm)

[image: Image of connectors]

***EDIT @xmojmr's request, here is an updated diagram that I found [here](http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/class-diagram-relationships/) (detailed definitions can be found in the linked page):

[image]

Comment: according to Wikipedia "..The UML 2.0 major revision replaced version 1.5 in 2005..". The article you are referencing is dated 2002 so it describes UML 1.x which is already outdated, obsoleted and can cause misunderstandings when reading newer UML documents. Can you link a more up-to-date article?

Comment: much nicer now. But I've already voted up your answer before my 1st comment. Maybe someone else passes by and appreciates your effort :)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to read UML superstructure specification. Read Classes section to get
information about types of relationship applicable to structural diagrams defined in UML, and much more. This document is base document if you want to learn UML. Dowload it from this site [UML Superstructure](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)

Comment: I think that jumping directly to the UML specification is very difficult for people who approaching UML for the first time so UML reference manual and UML user guide are good start for me but the problem with them is they are old versions and many acronyms changed.Did you have any hints about this?any ideas?

Comment: Yes, Superstructures is not suited for learning. It's even hard to digest for pro users.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is U.M.L.

You do can learn about applying Design Patterns, without getting into U.M.L., but, the original book, as well as, a lot of documentation uses U.M.L.

I suggest to learn about U.M.L., without Design Patterns, and later, learn about Design Patterns, with & without U.M.L.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: since when is UML wriiten with dots?

Comment: @qwerty_so It does not, but had to add them in ascii diagrams due sometimes spaces are compacted and deform the diagrams ...

Comment: You aren't using ASCII diagrams here.