# Enterprise Architect Relationships

Tags: uml, relationship, enterprise-architect

This is a generic post aimed at clarifying the differences among the relationships in Enterprise Architect.

There are a lot of relationships, such as association, dependency, realization, etc.

It would be probably very useful to get a clear overview for each so that it would be better understood and used in the most proper way.

If you have a best practice on the topic, please enrich our knowledge with your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430581/understanding-diagrams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question related to UML notation, not only to Sparx EA.
So, I suggest to check UML2 documentation, for example you can start from wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Links