# many to many relationship in uml

Tags: java, uml

i'm working on a java Lap for course and student . I'm create class for student with 
vector< studentcoruse> and create class called course with vector  and create class called studentcourse have attribute grade and object from class student and course

Q: now how connected between class student and course

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not appropriate for this site. Please visit [what can I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Some links to class diagramming basics are available in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24445528/2626313