# What is the inheritance symbol used in ERD diagram?

Tags: database, inheritance, uml, symbols, erd

I am certain that the inheritance symbol used in ERD diagram is the triangular symbol.

However, I am uncertain of the symbol used in UML diagram that is used to symbolize inheritance.

I have searched on the Internet and I have seen the symbol of a circle icon with an underline below it.

May I know which is the correct inheritance symbol used in UML diagram?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430581/understanding-diagrams)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Generalization as Realization have a triangle endpoint.

The difference is the dotted line for Realization (implementation) vs the solid line for Generalization (inheritance).

[image: Generalization and Realization]

Answer (score 2):

In the world of ER modeling, what you are describing is called generalization/specialization.  Another phrase is "is-a relationships.  For a related wikipedia article, [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) and scroll down to UML.

Answer (score 0):

It is triangle for generalization (inheritance), and can be circle (lollipop notation) for realization (implementation of an interface).