# C# UML Class Diagrams

Tags: c#, uml, diagram

I'm currently studying UML Class Diagrams and am a little confused with something. So I have my classes, inheriting and using interfaces, but where do I put the classes that don't inherit or use an interface? Do I just leave them off to the side like the image below?

[image: Rough UML Diagram]

Comment: Sure you can do that.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks, Is it the correct way to go about it? I've tried finding out about it but can't find too much on it

Comment: See also [Stack Overflow: Understanding Diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430581/understanding-diagrams)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your classes are related somehow and not an assortment of cobble stones. You show the relations between the classes by connecting them with an association (just a straight line). This way you can nicely see how the system is connected.